# Ubuntu nodejs pm2 and forever get ENOENT errors for accessing /tmp dir

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, forever, pm2

I have a ubuntu 14.04 server on digital ocean.

It's running nodejs (restify) It uploads files, and after uploading moves them from /tmp to my storage directory.

When running `sudo node app.js` it has access to the /tmp dir. When I use pm2 or forever, I get an error ENOENT.

I chmod 777 the /tmp dir and did a chown for the root (as that's what I'm running pm2 and forever under).

But everytime I upload a new file, the permissions on the newly uploaded file aren't 777.

**How can I make all new files in /tmp have 777 permissions, or allow pm2 or forever to let the script access it?**

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it was erroring with an ENOENT on the tmp directory, although it was a seperate issue.

The directory I was moving it to didn't exist. I was using relative urls in the script, and so when running as forever / pm2, it wasn't matching.

Fixed using path module and using full urls to files.

Hope this helps someone